# joining 2 csv files

Tags: python, bash, csv, join, awk

join.awk

```
#!/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=",";
    print "ozone,particullate_matter,carbon_monoxide,sulfure_dioxide,nitrogen_dioxide,longitude,latitude,timestamp,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,medianMeasuredTime,Distance between 2 points,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh"
}
NR==FNR && NR>1 {
    a[$8]=$1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $4 FS $5 FS $6 FS $7
}
FNR>1 {
if ($6 in a) {
    split(a[$6],data,FS);
    if ((data[6]==$11 || data[6]==$13) && (data[7]==$10 || data[7]==$12)) {
         print data[1],data[2],data[3],data[4],data[5],data[6],data[7],$6,$2,$3,$5,$14,$15,$16
        }
    }
}
```

I have this code which merges two csv files having 3 common columns. I got this code with the help of people in stackoverflow.

Inputfile1

```
ozone,particullate_matter,carbon_monoxide,sulfure_dioxide,nitrogen_dioxide,lon    gitude,latitude,timestamp
101,94,49,44,87,10.1050,56.2317,1406831700
106,97,48,47,86,10.1050,56.2317,1406832000
107,95,49,42,85,10.1050,56.2317,1406832300
103,90,51,44,87,10.1050,56.2317,1406832600
```

Inputfile2

```
status,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,extID,medianMeasuredTime,TIMESTAMP,vehicleCount,_id,REPORT_ID,Lat1,Long1,Lat2,Long2,Distance between 2 points,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh
OK,74,50,668,74,1406831700,5,20746220,158324,56.2317,10.1050,56.2258,10.1166,1030,52,71
OK,73,50,668,73,1406859900,6,20746392,158324,56.2317,10.1050,56.2258,10.1166,1030,52,71
OK,61,60,668,61,1406832300,4,20746723,158324,56.2317,10.1050,56.2258,10.1166,1030,52,71
OK,61,60,668,61,1406860500,1,20747172,158324,56.2317,10.1050,56.2258,10.1166,1030,52,71
```

Output

```
ozone,particullate_matter,carbon_monoxide,sulfure_dioxide,nitrogen_dioxide,longitude,latitude,timestamp,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,medianMeasuredTime,Distance between 2 points,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh
101,94,49,44,87,10.1050,56.2317,1406831700,74,50,74,1030,52,71
107,95,49,42,85,10.1050,56.2317,1406832300,61,60,61,1030,52,71
```

Each input files have 1300000+ rows.

When i run this command 
`awk -f  join.awk Inputfile1.csv Inputfile2.csv`

I get only the headers getting printed. But this code worked with smaller files. 
Please help

Comment: Does the command finish?

Comment: `awk -f  join.awk ip1.csv ip2.csv 
ozone,particullate_matter,carbon_monoxide,sulfure_dioxide,nitrogen_dioxide,longitude,latitude,timestamp,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,medianMeasuredTime,Distance between 2 points,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh`

it stops after this

Comment: Does it complete though or does it hang?

Comment: Yes it completes sir

Comment: your key should be `$10` not `$8` based on the values in the sample input files.

Comment: should i put a[$10] instead of a[$8] ? @karakfa

Comment: I think @karakfa mixed up the decimal separators with field separators...

Comment: One thing it is missing is `next` in the end of the `NR==FNR` block which shouldn't cause the problem you describe.

Comment: My old eyes tricked me.  Not $10.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` to merge the two files and then print out the columns you want:

```
join -j 1 -t ',' <( awk '{printf "%d,%s\n", NR, $0}' < test_file1 ) <( awk '{printf "%d,%s\n", NR, $0}' < test_file2 ) | awk -F ',' ' {print $2 FS $3}'
```

Let's break it down:

First, we prefix each line with a line number and a comma:

```
awk '{printf "%d,%s\n", NR, $0}' < test_file1
```

We use bash redirection to send the output into the join command.

```
# Join on field 1 (-j 1) using a seperator comma ( -t , )
join -j 1 -t ',' file_1 file_2
```

Finally, we pipe that to awk to print out our fields:

```
awk -F ',' ' {print $2 FS $3 FS $8}'
```

Comment: sir i wanna join based on 3 columns, i.e based on timestamp, longitude of file1 comparing it with 2 longitude values of file2, similarly latitude. @coder_man

Comment: You could compare the fields in the awk statement. So instead of printing you could do the if statement and then print. You'll probably want to do the join command and then just print out the first line and figure out which columns to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the code works and the files are fine it's only logical to assume that the data file hashed to `a` is too large. You could just split the `Inputfile1` and run each piece separately with `Inputfile2` like:

```
$ awk -f  join.awk Inputfile1_piece1.csv Inputfile2.csv
$ awk -f  join.awk Inputfile1_piece2.csv Inputfile2.csv
$ awk -f  join.awk Inputfile1_piece3.csv Inputfile2.csv
$ awk -f  join.awk Inputfile1_piece_etc.csv Inputfile2.csv
```

Depending on your data and `$8` in particular you may need to deal with duplicates; `a[$8]=$1 FS $2`... removes lines with duplicate timestamps where  random spliting may lead to duplicates. Sorting prior to spliting reduces the change of that but won't remove it completely so check the first and last timestamps of each file for matches.

**BUT:**

I did write the following awk script (more to satisfy own curiosity) but you could try it to your data. It assumes the files are sorted on the timestamp. It's not combat tested at all, only with the small sample data you provided and it seemd to weed out duplicated records, not sure if that's good or bad, though.

It reads records from 2 files and won't hash them to memory. While the timestamp from other file is smaller than from the other, keep wasting lines (hence the timestamps must be ordered).

```
BEGIN {FS=OFS="," }
NR==1 {                             # read, form and print header
    if(0>=getline line < file1)     
        exit
    print line,$2,$3,$5,$(NF-1),$NF
    next                            # and deal (off) with the first records
}
$6>=a[8] {
    while((getline line < file1) > 0 && (n=split(line,a)) && a[8] < $6)
        ;
    if(a[8]==$6 && (a[6]==$11 || a[6]==$13) && (a[7]==$10 || a[7]==$12) && n>0)
        print line,$2,$3,$5,$(NF-1),$NF
}
```

Running it (`Inputfile1` was already sorted on the timestamp, therefore it's read with `getline`. `Inputfile2` wasn't so it's sorted in process substitution. REMEMBER TO SORT YOUR DATA FILES):

```
$ awk -v file1="Inputfile1" -f foo.awk <(sort -t, -k6n Inputfile2)
ozone,particullate_matter,carbon_monoxide,sulfure_dioxide,nitrogen_dioxide,longitude,latitude,timestamp,avgMeasuredTime,avgSpeed,medianMeasuredTime,duration of measurements,ndt in kmh
101,94,49,44,87,10.1050,56.2317,1406831700,74,50,74,52,71
107,95,49,42,85,10.1050,56.2317,1406832300,61,60,61,52,71
```

There may be a million and a half errors, use at your own risk and if you do, validate, validate, validate the results. It only writes to stdout so it shouldn't destroy anything :D. (Everyone) Feel free to fix it if you see some illogicalities.

Comment: awk -v file1="pollutionfile.csv" -f newjoin.awk <(sort -t, -k6n traffile.csv)
ozone,particullate_matter,carbon_monoxide,sulfure_dioxide,nitrogen_dioxide,longitude,latitude,timestamp,56.21385651069573,10.144907008598352,10.246299305557386,0.0000,0.0000
This is the output i have got. I stops after this sir

Comment: And the files are sorted on the timestamp field? Is that data available anywhere?

Comment: i have sorted both the files based on timestamp field

Comment: Please give me links to exact files as there seems to be lots of variations.

Comment: I have made a lot of changes to the files sir. Shall i mail you ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7B7o7_9JHyvelBpbGU3ckpZc0k/view?usp=drivesdk     and     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7B7o7_9JHyvNkJRYjRpNmhRUUE/view?usp=drivesdk these are the drive links to two csv files @jamesBrown

Comment: Taking the data and your original code: `awk -f bar.awk pol.csv fin.csv | wc -l` ouputs `39403`.

Comment: `awk -f joincsv.awk pollutionfile.csv fintraffic.csv | wc -l` gave me
`1` I got this. Did you do any modifications to any files or the code sir ? @jamesbrown

Comment: Nope. What system are you on? One of the files had CRLF (Windows) line endings and the other had just CR (Linux etc).

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 sir. How do i change both to the same ? @jamesbrown

Comment: Use `file` to test the files and `unix2dos` to convert but I'm on Linux too, so that might not be the case.